# Connecting to MS SQL Server using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I am learning Javascript. My focus right now is React and Redux. I am trying to figure out how to connect to MS Sql Server to run database queries. Add and delete etc. I have been searching all over and have not found any tools to help guide me in the correct direction.

Do you some how run it using node.js?

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to stay away from Client Side JS so I am assuming I need to do this with node.js and somehow add server side files if I want to use JS.

Thank you in advance I know this is a pretty basic question.

Comment: Learn about server-side code.

Comment: Have a link to where I should start?

Comment: I would suggest starting FreeCodeCamp Back End Development Certification. Learn node.js and express.js and then move to connecting mssql.

Comment: @DavidBrierton [A rather simple tutorial I googled](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/access-sql-server-in-nodejs). Should be sufficient to give you a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everyone commented a brief pointer, let me give a bit more info so you can start.

JavaScript usually has two environments that it runs on. Client-side which is the `browser` and server-side which is `nodejs`. In the browser JS runs in a sandbox which is constrained to certain functionalities. Therefore, you cannot possibly connect to a database directly from your browser.

On the server,`nodejs`, however, you can do anything. Connect to a database and execute a query, read and write files, reach out to operating system APIs and many more.

Here is tutorial on how to set up things: [Tutorial: Setting up Node.js with a database](https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-node-js-with-a-database-part-1-3f2461bdd77f)